# Sum(ABS(col)) in LInq

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

What is an alternative of the following SQL in Linq to entities ? I am creating a LINQ query in Asp.Net MVC 3 with, EF 4.1:

```
SELECT Sum(ABS([Installment])) AS SumOfPayments FROM tblSchoolAccount
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
decimal SumOfPayments = db.tblSchoolAccounts.Sum(p => Math.Abs(p.Installment));
```

**EDIT**

If you REALLY want a query expression, this should work, but I think most developers would say the above is *much* clearer:

```
decimal SumOfPayments = (from p in db.tblSchoolAccounts
                        select Math.Abs(p.Installment)).Sum();
```

Comment: @Adam: I need to use it as a part of LINQ query so I dont think it will work. My query looks like this: from c in tblaccount join tblaccoutstatus ....

Comment: What I wrote **is** a linq query; I'm using "dot notation", while you're using a query expression.  You can use either.

Comment: Correction.  Usually you can use either, but for what you want, I'm pretty sure you're going to have to use the extension methods (like I have)

Comment: @Adam can I convert this to query expression notation ?

Comment: See above for a query expression, but at the end of it you still need to wrap in parenthesis and call an extension method.  Just stick with the original query; that's the standard way to write what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for the right answer, but I would like to suggest that payments are to be stored in `decimal` not in `double` due to rounding differences and differences in precision. Have look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Bazzz, you're right.  I have no idea what type is stored in his DB, but I'm assuming it's a decimal.  I've edited my answer.